# How to appropriately track memory allocations and frees in C++ with overloads to operator news and operator deletes?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator, delete-operator, placement-new

Requirement: Tracking both allocations as well as deletions. Every allocation is identified with two parameters, let's call them P1 and P2 for now.

I use a globally overloaded placement new operator with two additional arguments

```
void * operator new(size_t size, parameter_1_t p1, parameter_2_t p2);
```

Size is populated appropriately at run time. I use p1 and p2 to index into a 2-D array where I increment the current usage for memory allocation categorized with (p1,p2) with "size".
Something like `2dArray[p1][p2].increment_current_bytes(size);`

Now, my question is, when I use placement delete, how do I get to know the size of the memory that is intended to be freed? I need to know it to update the 2-D array accordingly.
Tried writing this -

```
void * operator delete(void* ptr, size_t size, parameter_1_t p1, parameter_2_t p2);
```

Doesn't work, because there is no such operator delete provided in C++. It expects me to fill in size as part of the explicit call to operator delete function.

Reference - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete

Comment: *how do I get to know the size of the memory that is intended to be freed?* -- I think you need something a little more robust that actually keeps the size information.  After that call to `new`, do you just throw the `size` information away?  How do tools such as `valgrind` work?

Answer (score 0):

The operator delete is expected to only require the allocated pointer. It is up to the allocation library to use *private* structures to store the allocated size. For example it is common to allocate slightly more than what is asked and use the initial memory *before the returned pointer* for various house keeping variables. Versions trying to detect heap smashes also put a copy after the memory zone returned to caller (actually allocating the requested size plus twice the house-keeping size) and at de-allocation time control that both zone still contain the same informations.

If you have special requirements and use special parameters, you could either use a map indexed by the returned pointer, or mimic the standard library and use a private zone in the allocated blocs.

Answer (score 0):

That's because C++ doesn't keep track of the allocated memory's size. You have to bookkeep yourself. Two options that come to my mind are a record table or memory prefixing.

With a record table you basically store all allocations in something like a hash table. When `new` is called, store the resulting pointer in that table with the allocation size. When `delete` is called, simply look up that pointer in the table to get the size and remove it afterwards.

With prefixing you have to allocate more memory than actually requested. Then you store the size of the buffer in the first N bytes and return a pointer to the memory after N bytes. For example, if a user requests 20 bytes, you allocate 28 bytes (N = 8) and store the requested size of 20 in that first 8 bytes. Then you return a pointer to the remaining 20 bytes.
On `delete` you then read the 8 bytes before the given pointer to get the block size back.